# How do I keep the previous result on the page when outputting a new one?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to keep the previously submitted value on the screen after hitting the submit button. For example, If I enter `Apple` and press submit, `Apple` appears. However, if I enter `Banana`, `Apple` disappears and is replaced by `Banana`. Is there a way to keep `Apple` on the page after I submit `Banana`? Here's the HTML/JavaScript I'm using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>HTML JavaScript output on same page</title>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
      function showMessage() {
        var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
        display_message.innerHTML = message;
      }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form> 
        Enter message: <input type="text" id="message">
        <input type="button" onclick="showMessage()" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <p> Message is: <span id="display_message"></span> </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: simply add a + in there: `display_message.innerHTML+= ' ' + message;`

Comment: you just push value of input box in a js array/object and use a loop to display all the value you inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to join the inputs together. Depending on how you want that to appear on screen. In this example. I push each input into an array, then join the array with a comma and display the list.

If you are looking to do more complex layouts take a look at a  template language for example: http://handlebarsjs.com/

```
<body>
<form>
Enter message: <input type="text" id = "message">
<input type="button" onclick="showMessage()" value="submit" />
</form>
<p> Message is: <span id = "display_message"></span> </p>
</body>
```

JS

```
var entries=[];
function showMessage(){
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
entries.push(message);
display_message.innerHTML= entries.join(",");
}
```

Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/aq676/543/

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! This is perfect!

Comment: Can you accept my answer? Thank you. Glad to of helped.

Answer (score 0):

I added an extra line of code at the bottom of your function to clear the text input each time "submit"is clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var allMessages = "";
    function showMessage(){
        var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
        allMessages += message + " ";
        display_message.innerHTML= allMessages;
        document.getElementById("message").value = "";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    Enter message: <input type="text" id = "message">
    <input type="button" onclick="showMessage()" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <p> Message is: <span id = "display_message"></span> </p>
</body>
</html>
```